# Empty braces "[]" in search field are sometimes replaced by one or more plus signs "+"

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, search

Searching with one of those terms works just fine:

- **[]**
- **[html]**
- **[html] [css] [javascript]**
- **[html] [css] []**
- **[] [css] [javascript]**

But in some other cases, when I remove a tag (like *double click the tag*, *hit delete*, *hit enter*) the empty braces "**[]**" are replaced by one or more plus signs like this:

- **[html] [] [javascript]** becomes **[html++javascript]**
- **[html] []** becomes **[html+]**
- **[] [css]** becomes **[+css]**

Is this a bug that in some cases the empty braces "**[]**" don't get filtered?

Comment: Oh my...you broke it! Why did you do that!? This is why we can't have anything nice...

Comment: ```[] [] [] []```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was that `[]` was being seen as an empty tag...that's not really valid at all, so starting with the next build it will be removed before the redirect.  It will also be removed from all other searches, though searching for `[]` in code if desired will still be supported by `"[]"`.  The way our parser worked just plain `[]` in a search didn't work for code *anyway*, so we're not losing anything just clearing some confusing behavior here.

Expect this build to go out tomorrow, I need someone else to look at an earlier change they made that I'm hesitant to build out at the moment.